# Gostaria de ajuda para entender o erro do meu código:

Tags: java

Fazer uma classe Ex1Primos para:
• Receber um inteiro N do usuário
• Testar se este inteiro é primo ou não e informar

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {   public static void main(String[] args) {

  Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);

  int Num;

  System.out.println("Digite um numero: ");   
  Num = ler.nextInt();

    if(Num > 1 && Num % 1 == 0 && Num % Num == 0){
      System.out.println(Num + " é um numero primo");
    } else {
      System.out.println(Num + " N é um numero primo");
    }    } }
```

Comment: Por que você acha que seu código tem um erro ? Mostre o erro do console, mostre o comportamento esperado e o comportamento que está ocorrendo para entendermos o seu ponto.

Comment: @VictorBier gostaria que o usuário digitasse um numero int, e imprimisse na tela se ele é um numero primo ou não. porém acredito que estou fazendo a condição errado.  Já que ele está imprimindo 4 como numero primo.

Comment: `%` retorna o resto da divisão. Então `Num % 1` e `Num % Num` sempre serão zero (pois ao dividir um número por 1 ou por ele mesmo, o resto sempre é zero). Ou seja, sempre vai entrar no `if`. De qualquer forma, o site está cheio de perguntas sobre números primos, vc pode achar alguns [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8697/112052)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

tudo bem?

Sim, seu código tem alguns erros para o fim que voce gostaria, pois ele sempre vai cair na primeira condição do IF, ou seja, sempre será verdadeiro

Pensa o seguinte: Vamos supor que o Num lido foi 4

aí ele cai no If
Vamos substituir as variáveis Num pelo seu valor, que é 4

```
if(4 > 1 && 4 % 1 == 0 && 4 % 4 == 0)
```

Viu que tudo dá verdade? e 4 não é numero primo

Pra realizar uma consulta desde o numero 0 até o numero que vai ser lido, você irá precisar usar um loop, pode ser um while ou for:

```
int contadorPrimo = 0;
for(int i = 1; i<=Num ; i++) {
    if(i % 1 == 0 && i % Num == 0) {
        contadorPrimo = contadorPrimo + 1;
    }

if (contadorPrimo == 2) {
    System.out.println(Num + " é um número primo");
} else {
    System.out.println(Num + " não é número primo");
}
```

A lógica:

Para só pra pensar como calculamos o numero primo: verificamos se ele é divisível por 1 e por ele mesmo, mas do 1 até o numero que estamos verificando, se não tiver nenhum outro divisível por ele mesmo, logo o numero verificado é primo, senão ele não é.

Exemplo: Numero = 8

Primeiro verifica se é divisível por 1 (no caso ele é, logo temos 1 numero pra dividir o 8)
Verifica se é divisível por 2 (sim, ele é divisível por 8) - Aqui já dava pra afirmar que o 8 não é primo porque ele tem outro numero divisível por ele além dele mesmo e o 1

Exemplo: Numero = 5

5 é divisível por 1? SIM;
5 é divisível por 2? nao;
5 é divisível por 3? nao;
5 é divisível por 4? nao;
5 é divisível por 5? SIM;

aqui vemos que o 5 é divisível por 1 e por ele mesmo, entao ele é primo

o Algoritmo deve percorrer todos os numeros desde do 1 até o numero escolhido, e durante esse percurso ele dever ser divisível somente por 1 e por ele mesmo.

Entendeu?

Comment: Entendi sim Thiago, valeu pela explicação.